# Camera culling- option not available

Tags: camera

To limit the memory usage of my scene(which is more complex then given below) I wanted to  use camera cull, but the option seems to be greyed out. How can I use this feature?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the camera cull option in the scene->simplify panel